# PAM 1000 Protocol Software Needed for Gilbarco Pump Controller

Tags: windows, api

I have tried to get my hands on some API or service that would enable me to take control of Gilbarco pmp. Where Can I find a software tool for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did a ton of research people. Hence the reason I am here now. I was on their site and all over the internet looking. I guess maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the docs from Veeder.  The index is at http://www.veeder.com/gold/gold_public_access.cfm?section_id=331, but you might want to start at http://www.veeder.com/us/search/google_appliance/PAM%201000?page=3 and look for the Gilbarco PC Pump Interface (direct link to the PDF does not work).  If all you need is the hardware interface and control software, the PDF should have the information you need.  If you need more, it has references for the full set of control and diagnotic manuals, which you can find at the link to the Veeder index, above.